# Simulate errors with PayPal's Smart Payment Buttons

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

First of all, i do not know what's the difference between PayPal Checkout and Smart Payment Buttons. Some clarification on this would be nice.

I use Smart Payment Buttons. Everything works. But I want to be able to simulate errors in Sandbox.

I tried following this:
[How can I simulate an error using Paypal Payments Pro sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736548/how-can-i-simulate-an-error-using-paypal-payments-pro-sandbox)

I got Negative Testing enabled successfully. And i have noticed that there are 2 methods to do negative testing.

**Method 1: test values.**

The problem is that these test-values seems completely unrelated to Smart payment Buttons. In fact, they say this:

> You can use the test values-based method to test the following **Payouts API** methods

I do not have anything called "Payouts API" in my SDK, nor do they speak of it in the documentation.

**Method 2: request headers**

They say this:

> Use the v1/payments/payment or v1/payments/payment payment_id/execute API endpoint.

Same problem. I do not know what is "payments/payment". Seems to be completely unrelated to Smart Payment Buttons.

I am really confused. Please help me understand how to simulate errors.

Comment: Any update on this? I can't find any information on this anywhere

Comment: No, no updates yet